# Finding the Ker(T) and Image(T)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$:${R^{5}}\to{P_{2}}$(R) be a linear transformation that has the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&3&2&0&-1\\2&6&4&6&4\\1&3&2&2&1\end{bmatrix}$,

relative to the bases {(1,1,1,1,1), (1,1,1,1,0), (1,1,0,0,0), (1,0,0,0,0), (0,0,0,1,0) of ${R^{5}}$ and {1 + x + $x^{2}$, x, 1} of ${P_{2}}$(R)

A) Find Ker(T)

B) Find Image(T)

So we have to find the set of vectors in ${R^{5}}$ that are sent to the 0 vector of ${P_{2}}$, and with the Image, we have to find the set of vectors such that T(V) = W, were V is a vector in the ${R^{5}}$ and W is a vector in ${P_{2}}$.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Row Reduced the Matrix, but I am not sure what that corresponds to, s.t the first and fourth rows have a leading term.  Do we have to row reduce the the matrix formed by the respective bases?

Comment: First and fourth rows? of a matrix that has only three rows to begin with? I think you had better show us what you got when you did the row reduction, maybe then someone will be able to help you out.

Comment: Are you still here?